# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "|"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, sqoop

I have imported a table into HDFS as

> fields-terminated-by '|'

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://connection \
--username  \
--password  \
--table products \
--as-textfile \
--target-dir /user/username/productsdemo \
--fields-terminated-by '|'
```

after that, I am trying to read it as RDD using spark-shell version 1.6.2

```
var productsRDD = sc.textFile("/user/username/productsdemo")
```

and converting it into a data frame

```
var productsDF = productsRDD.map(product =>{ 
var o = product.split("|");
products(o(0).toInt,o(1).toInt,o(2),o(3),o(4).toFloat,o(5))
}).toDF("product_id", "product_category_id","product_name","product_description","product_price","product_image" )
```

But When I try to print the output it is throwing the below exception.

**java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "|"**

Why I am getting this error can anyone help me out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` are use `regex` to do the split string, since `|` is a special character in regex means `OR` You need to use `\\|` instead of `|` when split

```
var o = product.split("\\|");
```

Comment: It worked like a charm Thanks mate where can I learn these kind of simple ones